# How to Arch an Image to Fit a Tikz Decorations Page

Tags: tikz-pgf, includegraphics, decorations, tikz-pic, tikz-decorations

Consider:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{PrussianBlue}{cmyk}{1,.41,0,.67}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\tikzset{mydecor/.style 2 args={decoration={text along path,
        text align={left indent=2em},
        text={|\Large|#2},
        },
      yshift=#1,
      decorate}}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[PrussianBlue] (-6,0) rectangle (6,9) (180:0.45cm) arc (180:360:0.45cm);
  \draw[line width=0.3cm,PrussianBlue!45,fill=white,miter limit=1]
      (0,0.45) to[controls={+(150:2.25cm) and +(25:2.25cm)}] (-5.4,0.6) --
      (-5.4,9.6) to[controls={+(25:2.25cm) and +(150:2.25cm)}]
      (0,9) to[controls={+(30:2.25cm) and +(155:2.25cm)}] (5.4,9.6) --
      (5.4,0.6) to[controls={+(155:2.25cm) and +(30:2.25cm)}]
      (0,0.45) -- (0,9);
% Left page
  \path[mydecor={-7ex}{How to fit an image}] (-5.4,9.6) to[controls={+(25:2.25cm) and +(150:2.25cm)}] (0,9);
  \path[mydecor={-7ex-2\baselineskip}{To the entire page?}] (-5.4,9.6) to[controls={+(25:2.25cm) and +(150:2.25cm)}] (0,9);
% Right page
  \path[mydecor={-7ex}{I would like to}] (0,9) to[controls={+(30:2.25cm) and +(155:2.25cm)}] (5.4,9.6);
  \path[mydecor={-7ex-2\baselineskip}{place an image}] (0,9) to[controls={+(30:2.25cm) and +(155:2.25cm)}] (5.4,9.6);
  \path[mydecor={-7ex-4.2\baselineskip}{ on the left page.}] (0,9) to[controls={+(30:2.25cm) and +(155:2.25cm)}] (5.4,9.6);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\vspace*{10pt}

\includegraphics[width=6cm,height=9cm]{example-image-A}
\end{document}
```

which produces the output:

[image]

QUESTION: How may I fit the A-image to the left-hand page of the displayed book so that the image when inserted in the book---appears to be naturally arched?

Thank you.

Comment: It is possible to transform images using PGFPlots by adding them as a surface to a 3D plot, I think. But otherwise you would need to split the picture into several parts and arrange them in a way so that they follow the curve. There is no out-of-the-box way to transform an image in this way as far as I know.